# How to reference a header component in React Native

Tags: react-native, reference, header, navigation

I am making a React Native application in which users can place comments on certain topics. I have a stacknavigator with a custom `<SubscribeButton />` in the header.

When a user looks up a topic, they can click the button to (un)subscribe and the layout of the button changes accordingly. The logic and server call to (un)subscribe are all in the custom component.

What I now want to do, is have a user subscribe automatically when they place a comment on the topic. Normally, I'd reference this custom component with `ref={ref => this._subscribeButton = ref}` and then call `this._subscribeButton.subscribe()`. However, since the component is in the stacknavigator's header, I can't seem to reference it and the reference evaluates to *undefined*.
Is there a nice way to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: it would be better if you create your won custom header and disable the stacknavigator header, so that there you can access the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

rather than referencing a header component with 'this', they can be referenced with 'navigation':

```
<MyComponent
  ref={myComp => navigation.myComp = myComp} 
/>
```

And simply call with:

```
this.props.navigation.myComp.subscribe()
```